# BCD Up-Counter Schematic Error

Tags: digital-logic, simulation, schematics, ise

When I try to simulate my schematic for my up counter, i get the error

> Net "Net-name" cannot be connected both to an input port and an instance output pin.

[Here is my schematic](https://i.imgur.com/tGvqCXZ.jpg)

I am pretty sure the error is because of how to output of the flip flops is sent back into the input, but I thought that is how the design of an up-counter is supposed to be implemented. Is that not true?

I found [this](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/21449.htm) when searching the error, which states:

> "Error: DesignEntry:222" indicates that an I/O Marker with an Input Port polarity is connected to an output pin of one of the symbol instances in the schematic drawing. This is not allowed, as it would create an electrical source conflict.

I think that this is my problem, but I am not sure what to do about it. I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Where did you get the ideas for this up-counter of yours?  You should never have the output of one of your flip-flops directly tied as feedback to an input line.  Suppose the input is low and the flip-flop output is high? What then? Or vice versa? Some quick googling comes up with a schematic much different from yours. http://sub.allaboutcircuits.com/images/04353.png

You should probably try to be a little more detailed about what you're doing, the type of counter, so on and so forth when you start off your question.  It's confusing, and many people around here will downvote you for this.

Comment: @krb686 My goal is to combine a BCD up counter with a couple other labs that we have done in class(a BCD to 7-seg decoder, and a BCD to school ID design), so that my school ID number prints out on the 7 segment display on an FPGA. I tied the outputs to the inputs so that the current state will affect the next state (so if current state is 0000, that number will go through my logic and the next state will come out of the flip flops as 0001). I assumed that the outputs tied to the inputs was the problem,but I don't know how else I could have the current state have an influence on the next state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*I tied the outputs to the inputs so that the current state will affect the next state (so if current state is 0000, that number will go through my logic and the next state will come out of the flip flops as 0001).*"

**Mealy Machines**

You are correct that a mealy machine's next input is affected *by the current state, and the inputs*, but you're going about it the wrong way.

You can't just simply tie the output back to the input line.  That doesn't make any sense, because you have 2 driving elements for a single line.  If your input line doesn't match the output line tied to it, you have a short!

---

Since you're learning about mealy machines, I'm sure you've already done state diagrams.

*They don't teach you them for no reason*.

You need to start off with a state diagram of your mealy machine, like this:

[image]

You draw a bubble for each possible state, arrows between transitions determining what state change occurs depending on current state and input.  You see numbers like **0/0**. This means the input was a 0, and the output during the transition was a 0. So in the above diagram, in state S0 with an input of 0, the state changes to S1 and the output is a 0.

After you have a completed state diagram, you can then make a **state transition table**.

**State transition table**

[image]

You fill in the state transition table from the values in your state diagram.

You also need to encode your states in some binary form, such as in a **state encoding table**

[image]

With your states now encoded, you can substitute the encoded values into your above state table and end up with something like this:

[image]

Notice how now, instead of a single column for next state, you have 2 columns for each bit of the next state.

I usually tack on the outputs to the right side of my encoded state table, but you also need the values for your outputs.

**These images are not from the same example, so they won't make sense together.  They are just examples of the tables**
[image]

At this point, you can then translate these into karnaugh maps or deduce the logic you will need for the circuit.

**Karnaugh Maps**

If your logic is fairly complex, karnaugh maps will be the best way to go.

You will need to create a karnaugh map for each bit of the next state, and each bit of the output.

So for example in the above tables (excluding the last one), there are 2 next-state bits, so I would need a separate karnaugh map for each of those bits.  Then I would need another for the output bit.  Each map could have horizontal axis being both current state bits, and vertical axis being both input bits.

**In review, here are the steps you need to take, in order**

[image]

Finally, you may end up with something that looks similar to this (but perhaps more complex):

[image]

So yes, **there is a feedback where the output affects the next state, but it doesn't just tie directly to the input line.  It most likely will go into some combinational logic, like a gate that is shared with the input**

**Photo Credit**
All images come from the text *Digital Design and Computer Architecture, 2nd Edition*, by David Money Harris and Sarah L. Harris, pgs. 133-140

Comment: Please provide a citation for the images that you have copied into your answer.

Comment: @krb686 I understand what I was doing wrong now and figured out how to fix it. Thanks for your awsome reply it helped a lot and I really appreciate it!

Comment: Photo credit has been added. And you're welcome, LurkDog

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you want the latch values to be determined by the inputs in some situations, and by the present latched values in other cases.  To accomplish that, I would suggest feeding each input along with the corresponding latch output into a 2:1 multiplexing circuit; have the four multiplexing circuits select between the four latch outputs and the four data inputs, based upon the state of an additional "load" input.  Depending upon where the multiplexers are placed, hitting the clock with "load" high and some bit pattern on the input may either load the specified input directly, or load the state that follow after the specified bit pattern.